# wiringPiISR function is not working with nanopi neo

Tags: interrupt, gpio, wiringpi, nanopi

I am trying to set up the interrupt on a GPIO of `NanoPi-NEO-LTS`. But the program always says `"WiringPiISR is not implemented"`, even with the exact example isr.c available on `GitHub`.

I already tried the programs from wiringPi. but it always shows the error.

Can someone help?